# Building custom Mixed Reality (Augmented Reality) setup in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I'm tasked with developing an application, which would emulate augmented reality in a virtual reality application. We are using Google Cardboard (Google VR), and want to show the camera images (don't mind the actual camera setup, say I already have the images) to the user.
I'm wondering about the ways to implement it. Some ideas I had:

1. **Substituting the images rendered for each eye by my custom camera images**.
   Here I have the following problems: I don't know how to actually replace the images that are rendered to the screen, let alone to each eye. And how to afterwards show some models overlayed on top of the image (I would assume by using the Stencil Buffer?).
2. **Placing 2 planes in from of the camera with custom images rendered onto it**
   In this case, I'm not sure about the whole "convenience" of the user experience, as the planes would most likely be placed really close, so you only see one plane with one eye, and not the other. Seems like it might put some strain onto your eyes, because they would close on something that is really close to you.

Somehow I haven't found a project that would try to achieve something like that, and especially with all the Windows Mixed Reality related stuff polluting the search results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vuforia digital eyewear, here is the [documentation](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Vuforia-for-Digital-Eyewear) for it.
And a [simple tutorial on YouTube](https://youtu.be/WvHGAAv1cM4).